# How to change the opacity and height of border in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

**What I have:**

I have the following code

```
\newtcolorbox{DefinitionBlue}{
enhanced,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
coltitle=my-blue-2,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{my-blue-2},
opacityback=0
}
```

and in the document

```
\begin{DefinitionBlue}
This is a test
\end{DefinitionBlue}
```

which produces the following output

[image]

(note that I have set the background to be like this in the whole document; it is not a result of the colorbox)

**What I want to do:**

I want to create a highlighter effect (as if I have highlighted before the text), that is, I want the border to have lower opacity and I want to be able to change the height of the border. I have tried using the highlighter command, however, it is not flexible enough for me.

Can someone help me change the opacity and height of the border?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: a hand sketch of the desired output would help perhaps

Comment: @jsbibra thank you for the suggestion. I have added a sketch now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is the border width, the second one is a shift and the third one is a list of options.

```
borderline west={10pt}{5pt}{blue, opacity=0.5}
```

To reduce the height we need an other approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{DefinitionBlue}{
enhanced,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
coltitle=blue,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
left=5mm,
%borderline west={10pt}{5pt}{blue,opacity=0.5},
overlay={
      \draw[line width=10pt,blue,opacity=0.5]
          ([shift={(3mm,-2mm)}]interior.north west)
          --([shift={(3mm,2mm)}]interior.south west);
        }
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
zrzer rzerz 
\begin{DefinitionBlue}
This is a test\\
Thid is as test\\
This is as test

\end{DefinitionBlue}
\noindent
dzaez zzrze
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment! I wanted to also ask, do you know how one can also change the height? The one I have right now goes above and below my text too much. I would like to make it a bit shorter. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: @MathsWizzard aswer updated